# Unable to mock an object for a Durable task with nsubstitute. Getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: mocking, xunit, testcase, azure-durable-functions, nsubstitute

I'm new to nsubstitute and so far I've being doing great until I try to mock an object for a durable task method. It doesn't seem to pass values at all. What I'm I doing wrong?

Here is my method:

```
public async Task<List<FulfillmentProcess>> TriggerTableDataAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext ctx)
{
    var input = ctx.GetInput<EligibleMember>();
    var accountNumber = input.AccountNumber;
    var oe30Termdata = await  
    _getAllTriggerTableService.GetAllTriggerTableDataForOe30Async(accountNumber);
    return oe30Termdata.ToList();
}
```

These are classes being passed as context (ctx) and returned:

```
public class EligibleMember
{
    public string SubId { get; set; }
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
    public string PractitionerName { get; set; }
    public string MemberTerminationResonName { get; set; }
    public string MembersFullName { get; set; }
    public string MemberFirstName { get; set; }
    public string MemberLastName { get; set; }
    public string MemberMailingAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string ClaimId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string CoverageEndDate { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClaimLine { get; set; }
    public string TotalCharges { get; set; }
    public string DateOfService { get; set; }
    public string PaidThroughDate { get; set; }
    public string TodaysDate { get; set; }
    public string DueDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderResponseId { get; set; }
    public string CorrelationResponseId { get; set; }
    public string CorrespondenceName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
}   

public class FulfillmentProcess
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string CorrespondenceType { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string KeyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my test case:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CanCallTriggerTableDataAsync()
{
    _getAllTriggerTableService.GetAllTriggerTableDataForOe30Async(Arg.Any<string>())
    .Returns(Substitute.For<IEnumerable<FulfillmentProcess>>());
    var result = await _function.TriggerTableDataAsync(_activityCtx);
    await _getAllTriggerTableService.Received().GetAllTriggerTableDataForOe30Async(Arg.Any<string>());
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: When debugging, at what line is the exception raised?

Comment: Thank you Peter for replying! It raised "object not set to an instance of an object". But already figure it out. I completely forgot to create a fixture for the object I needed to pass like so:           
 public async Task CanCallTriggerTableDataAsync()
    {
        var eligibleMember = _fixture.Create<EligibleMember>();
        _activityCtx.GetInput<EligibleMember>().Returns(eligibleMember);
        var result = await _function.TriggerTableDataAsync(_activityCtx);
        result.Count().Should().Be(0);
    }